# Read .csv file with nested for loops, only getting last line

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I am trying to read in .csv file and create a 2-D array of floats values.  This is what I have done so far:

```
import csv
filename  = 'data_out.csv'   
# create an array for the for the data    
row_values = [None]*len(header)   
all_values = []

reader = csv.reader(open(filename,'rt'),delimiter=',')
next(reader) #skip header line
for row in reader:
    i=0
    for item in row:
        value = float(item)
        row_values[i]=value
        i=i+1
        print(row_values)
    all_values.append(row_values)

print(all_values)
```

The print (row_values) looks like it works.  Each row is put into a list of float values.  But when I print (all_values), it does not work.  I have created a list of lists (the correct number of rows), but it is only the last row of values repeated over and over again.  Perhaps I have the .append() in the wrong spot?

I should say this is my first time programming in python, but I have been programming in C++ for years.  Any help/tips would much appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: You have a serious problem with indentation. Either you dropped it when posting here or you did not understand that python uses indentation for flow control.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said.  It is Python version 3.3

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to format the code when posting here, but there is indentation in my code.

Comment: Just add spaces for indentation, typically 2 spaces (blanks) per level.

Comment: Nope, I keep adding spaces but it still looks the same.

Comment: Nope, looks better now ;-)

Comment: @user2098583: You need to add a blank line before and after the indented code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `all_values` is storing a *reference* to the array `row_values` every time you append it, *not a copy*. Therefore, all elements of `all_values` are references pointing to the same array, the values of which you are overwriting the values in `row_values` in each iteration.

See this, for example:

```
b = []

a = [1, 2]
b.append(a)
print b

a[0] = 3
b.append(a)
print b

print id(b[0]), id(b[1])
```

This has the same effect as your program, it will print `[[3, 2], [3, 2]]` for the second `print` statement. The last `print` statement shows the id of both values in `b`, which is the same, meaning that the two elements in b are the same element.

Therefore, a fixed (and more pythonic) version of your loop would be:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(filename,'rt'),delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    row_values = [float(item) for item in row]
    all_values.append(row_values)

print all_values
```

The third line uses a list comprehension to convert all values in `row` to floats and store them in a *new* array, which is then appended to `all_values`.

Comment: If you don't like list comprehensions, you can use the syntax "for i, item in enumerate(row):" to get the indice automatically :)

Comment: @MichaelClerx: True, this would have been a more pythonic approach. Still, this does not solve the problem of reusing the array.

Comment: Absolutely! Just adding to your answer :)

Comment: @user2098583 You could accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You only create one array object and append the same array object to the list. So only last row repeats in final output.

You should create the array object inside first level loop and append it to the list.